# How to insert a HTML character into this Html.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code to generate this:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Read", "Index", "News", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

[image]

But I want to make a button that looks like this (with the use of HTML character `&raquo;`):
[image]

However when I do the following:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Read &raquo;", "Index", "News", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

I get this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

Other solutions given here work. But just in case you are wondering, what to do if you dont have the special character on keyboard, here it goes:

You can either use

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "News")' class="btn btn-default">Read &raquo;</a>
```

OR

```
@Html.ActionLink(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Read &raquo;"), "Index", "News", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Answer (score 2):

The text will be encoded by ActionLink() implementation, so you don't need to do it. Just use that char in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Learn More »", "Index", "News", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })</p>
```

As @MatteoSp said, just use the actual character in your string.  The above `ActionLink` will give you a button as you desired.